# How to fit square image into circular Decoration Box FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to fit rectangle image inside circular boxdecoration. It instead is fitting inside the parent container. I don't want to fill the image inside decoration box. I just want to fit it inside circle without angles being clipped.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 15,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('I am a'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 450,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[Screenshot of Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv4c5.jpg)

Comment: Did you try to add ```fit: BoxFit.fill,``` to your ```NetworkImage``` ?

Comment: Yeah that will solve

Comment: @ikerfah I want to fot the rectangular image inside circle with all 4 corners visible (without being clipped).

Comment: Did you try ```fit: BoxFit.contain``` ?

Comment: yes I tried it. It didn't work. Corners of image is still clipped.